# Get only the Date from the WPF DatePicker

Tags: wpf, date, datepicker

when I bind the wpf datepicker SelectedDate I get this 2010-08-25 08:15:33.

As I do a comparison:

```
if (SelectedStart >= SelectedEnd)
     return false;
else
    return true;
```

I get always true. I have to compare the DATE without the TIME. But I do not want to convert to a string and parse this then as a Date. That would be silly.

Hm the control is called DATEpicker not DATETIMEpicker seems MS did naming mistake ;P

I already tried this: `SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedStart, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}"`

But I always get the full DateTIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (SelectedStartDate.Date >= SelectedEndDate.Date)
```

This will compare only the date part of the `DateTime`

Comment: argh... and I looked all time so strongly at the properties of the Control. thanks a bunch Thomas.